# WinJs creating files on the fly in installedLocation

Tags: javascript, permissions, navigation, local, winjs

I am developing WinJs app and I want to create several files in my app installed location in order to navigate to them locally. When I am trying to create new file I am getting Access denied exception :

"WinRTError: Access is denied"

This is the code which I'm using for file creation:

```
var folder = Windows.ApplicationModel.Package.current.installedLocation;
folder.createFileAsync("index.html", Windows.Storage.CreationCollisionOption.replaceExisting)
```

Is there a way to allow this functionality, or is it just blocked for security reasons and there's nothing that you can do about it?

- Craeting those files in local folder cause another issue that I want to prevent - that's why I am trying to create them in installed location.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can't do that ! this folder is a read-only.

But ... (if you have to do this)

You can write anithing in the localFolder

```
Windows.ApplicationModel.Package.current.LocalFolder
```

And write a lot of code to read this files that you created, to load them dynamically in your app

Comment: But I wrote that I can't use local folder :)

Comment: Yeah, I see that, that's why I wrote "you have to write a lot of code" ;)

Because you can not do  the classical WinJS navigation. You have to load yours file as a templates and do stuff with it in memory.

Comment: You see, my problem is that I want to navigate to some html file from WinJs application which is downloaded on the fly. I didn't found a way to perfiorm a navigation to html page in my local folder from WinJs (Windwos 8.1) application  as x-ms-wbview, iframe or by location.href usage.

Comment: Sadly, this is simply not possible.

To do that, you have to code all the plumbing to load your "new" html file as a WinJS template and inject them in your app on runtime.

Comment: Ca you give me a hint on how to implement that WinJs template ? I gues, what you mean is WinJS.Binding.Template, how can I set its content with my "new" html

Comment: Not necessarily, you have a blank page and you insert your html when you navigate to this page.